# sql,buffer of a centroid, projection in qgis

Tags: sql, buffer, qgis

I would like to create a buffer of 100 m around a centroid. To do this, I wrote the following query:

```
update table SET ddr = ST_Buffer(centroid,100)
```

the SRID of centroid is 4326. The SRID of buffer is the same.

When I want to look at it in qgis, I defined:

- the SRC of the layer with the centroid as WSG84 and the SRC of the Google streets map as WSG 84/Pseudo Mercator . the point is well placed
- If I put the SRC of the layer holding the buffer as WSG84, I obtain an oval much larger than 100 m.

what is it due to?  When I set the SRID of my background map as WSG84, the buffer appears as a circle but the centroid and the buffer are misplaced.

Could you explain me carefully what happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the projection that your layer is in to WSG84 before you run the SQL statement placing your centroids. If you set it then change the projection, you're bound to get distortion of both placement of the centroids and the size/shape of your 100m circles. 
Do you want your end projection to be in 4326 or in WSG 84?